# How do I work with string matching using %?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-matching

There is a table that looks like below. I want to match sender's and receiver's names. In this example, I'm only interested in ABC and DEF as their names match (not a complete match but that is ok). How do I extract cases similar to ABC and DEF?

Table A:

| id | sender full name | receiver first name | receiver last name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | mike smith brown | mike | smith |
| DEF | kate josefin baker | kate | baker williams |
| GHI | kim jones | nathan | wilson |

Comment: Your exact requirement is not clear. It is enough to only check the first name of the receiver or is also the last name important? Or to ask in another way: When I change in the last row of your sample input the first name to kim, will this be a match or not?

Comment: What's important is that sender's full name includes what's shown in reciever first name and receiver last name. That's why even if sender full name includes something other than what's written in reciever's first name and last name, it is ok. To your second question, if the receiver's first name is changed to kim, that would still not be a match as sender full name does not include wilson. Hope it's clearer now!

Comment: To make it short: In my opinion, this is too risky and complex in SQL and should be done in another application. You could do something like SPLIT_PART(sender,' ',1) AS sender1,
SPLIT_PART(sender,' ',2) AS sender2,
SPLIT_PART(sender,' ',3) AS sender3 and the same for the receiver and then do an IN clause over the results, but this is very bad practice and there will be lots of options that will let such a query fail. You should find a better way to store the data which makes it safer to do such comparisons.